# Oracle forms using array error

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using Oracle Forms and Reports. I am a beginner.

I have a table `invoice` having fields `INVNO`,`INVDATE`.

Invoice table:

```
Invno    Invdate
INVNO1   03/03/2017
```

Another table passing having these fields :

`Passing` table

```
Invno       debitcode  credit    amount sln 
INVNO1      debit1     credit1   100    1
INVNO1      debit2     credit2   200    2 
INVNO1      debit3     credit3   150    3
INVNO1      debit4     credit4   250    4
```

Number of records for `debit` and `credit` may vary and maximum number of records is 7.

In a form I want to display a horizontal row of record depending on number of records

```
Invoice No Debit1 Credit1 Amount Debit2 credit2 Amount ..Debit4 Credit4
```

Comment: @APC on the flip side, others who read his comment about DV will likely DV just because they read it

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs - Highly unlikely. The number of actively malicious people on StackOverflow with sufficient rep to downvote is pretty low.

Answer (score 0):

Forms can't do anything "dynamic", so you'll have to hardcode all 7 credit/debit values, such as this (I've done it up to 3 values). I'd suggest you to create a **view** based on such a query:

```
SQL> with passing (invno, debit, credit, amount, sln) as
  2    (select 'invno1', 'debit1', 'credit1', 100, 1 from dual union
  3     select 'invno1', 'debit2', 'credit2', 200, 2 from dual union
  4     select 'invno1', 'debit3', 'credit3', 150, 3 from dual union
  5     select 'invno1', 'debit4', 'credit4', 250, 4 from dual)
  6  select invno,
  7    max(decode(sln, 1, debit)) debit1,
  8    max(decode(sln, 1, credit)) credit1,
  9    max(decode(sln, 1, amount)) amount1,
 10    --
 11    max(decode(sln, 2, debit)) debit2,
 12    max(decode(sln, 2, credit)) credit2,
 13    max(decode(sln, 2, amount)) amount2,
 14    --
 15    max(decode(sln, 3, debit)) debit3,
 16    max(decode(sln, 3, credit)) credit3,
 17    max(decode(sln, 3, amount)) amount3
 18  from passing
 19  group by invno;

INVNO  DEBIT1 CREDIT1    AMOUNT1 DEBIT2 CREDIT2    AMOUNT2 DEBIT3 CREDIT3    AMOUNT3
------ ------ ------- ---------- ------ ------- ---------- ------ ------- ----------
invno1 debit1 credit1        100 debit2 credit2        200 debit3 credit3        150
```

As of Reports: well, the simplest option is to reuse query (or a view, as I've suggested) you used in Forms. Or, if you feel like it, create a **matrix report** which is capable of doing it *dynamically*.

P.S. Oh, yes - forgot to ask: title says "error". Which error? You didn't specify it.

Comment: Thanks alot. You understand what I need.